# What is the right way to install React + Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have been using React with traditional javascript for sometime now and there has been no issue at all. But recently I'm trying to learn React + Typescript but it's not working at all. I created the React + Typescript app with `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`. But when I serve with `npm start`, there's this error that reads `

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\OGBEDADA\PhpstormProjects\react-blog\src'
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\OGBEDADA\PhpstormProjects\react-blog\src'

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 8:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals' in 'C:\Users\OGBEDADA\PhpstormProjects\react-blog\src'

webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

`

// Index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
```

// App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to React + Typescript</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals' in 'C:\Users\OGBEDADA\PhpstormProjects\react-blog\src'

reportWebVitals doesn't exist

Comment: I just reinstalled web vitals, still same error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).